# How should sensorManager.registerListener() be called in onResume()?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensormanager

I'm testing with an app that samples accelerometer data and process it.

First time the app is installed, the onSensorChanged() is called at 1/2 the rate of which is specify in samplePeriodUs

I've tried unregistering and register the sensorManager Listener in onPause(). One *hack* that do seem to work is to enter 1/2 the sample rate in the onResume(). That cannot be the correct way of doing things?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, 20000); }

 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, 10000);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this); }
```

I expect sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, 20000); to be used in onResume() and in onCreate()

Comment: If I remove sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, 20000); from onCreate() and put 20000 in the registerListener in onResume() it do work. But is this really correct?

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is strange indeed. Here is the approach I use to manage the sensors in my machine learning app.

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer, mGyroscope, mMagnetometer;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener, mGyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener, mMagnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorEventListener);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
    mGyroscope = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    mMagnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

/**
* Listener that handles sensor events
*/
private final SensorEventListener mSensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        //if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
            // Do work
        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            // Do work
        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            // Do work
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    }
};
```

The complete project source can be found at https://github.com/Wickapps/Activity-Tracker

Comment: Why only one registerListener in onCreate (mAccelerometer), but all three in onResume? In the official docs, registerListener is not called in onCreate at all, only in onResume, which looks confusing to me.